# music to Study for Excellence in Sound Design

Tags: creative-inspiration, sound-design

As an out-branching of Ryan's question about film sound design. I want to know what you think is the best musical sound design (for a lack of a better set of words).

The best example (off the top of my head) is Pink Floyd's "dark side of the moon". It follows similar "layering" as a film's sound track don't you think? In terms of the use of instruments (which tie the two together I think). Foley objects, footsteps even the human voice are "musical instruments".

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

check out [this thread](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/3713/inspiration-from-the-world-of-music-production), already in progress.